# Avoid Instantiation of IndirectList in Eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple OneToMany Relation between a Parent and a Child.

Parent:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

Child:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
private Parent parent;
```

Because a parent can have a big amount of children I wanted to take advantage of [Lazy Instantiation of Indirect Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/mappings/CollectionMapping.html#setUseLazyInstantiationForIndirectCollection(java.lang.Boolean)):

> IndirectList and IndirectSet can be configured not to instantiate the list from the database when you add and remove from them. IndirectList defaults to this behavior. When Set to true, the collection associated with this TransparentIndirection will be setup so as not to instantiate for adds and removes. The weakness of this setting for an IndirectSet is that when the set is not instantiated, if a duplicate element is added, it will not be detected until commit time.

As the default FetchType of OneToMany is LAZY and I am using a List for my Collection, loading a parent from the database causes an IndirectList to be used for the relation. As soon as I add another child to that parent I can see that a select query for the children of that parent is executed.

**How can I change that?**
I am using Eclipselink 2.6.4 (`org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.6.4`).

I also tried to use a DescriptorCustomizer to call `org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.setUseLazyInstantiationForIndirectCollection(Boolean)` on my relation, but this seemed to have absolutely no effect.

After debugging into the Method `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.add(E)`, I was able to see that the Method call to `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.shouldAvoidInstantiation()` at line 206 returned false, because `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList._persistence_getPropertyChangeListener()` at line 1007 returns null and null is not instanceof AttributeChangeListener. Because of this the relation is then instantiated by `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.getDelegate()` in line 216.

To me this seems like a bug, but I don't know enough about this implementation to be sure.

Comment: Are you using bytecode enhancement/weaving?  I believe change tracking is required to support what you are looking for, which is enabled using weaving as described here https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm

Comment: Thanks @Chris you are right, I was running my test scenario in eclipse without adding the eclipselink jar as an agent jar in my run configuration. I just read that weaving was enabled by default in java ee app servers, so I didn't think about that. when I run the test using my app server everything is fine and adding the agent jar to eclipse also fixes that issue. If you want, you can anwser this question with your comment and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change tracking is required to support not instantiating lazy collections when making modifications.  Change tracking is enabled when using weaving as described here: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm